# Indexing in remote c++ eclipse project does not start

Tags: c++, indexing, eclipse-cdt

I setup an remote C++ project in Eclipse Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0) using RSE..The project is located in OpenSuse VM and I am connected  from windows 10 machine.

Indexing does not start ,without any error. I tried the RDT Remote Fax Indexer without success as well

Thank you

Comment: How to reproduce this issue? Please show some code and tell the error message.

Comment: @howlger, no error is appeared in eclipse log. Just the indexing does not start..

Comment: CDT indexer doesn't work with remote projects. You can try with Eclipse PTP which provides better support but usually Eclipse is quite poor from this point of view.